# Encurtar palavras

Tags: php, html, html5

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço para encurtar a palavra pra ficar

> Illo qui facere...

Porem quando passar o mouse deve abrir um popover com o nome completo

> Illo qui facere temporibus ut adipisicing pariatur

Comment: Obrigado , Nao tinha percebido que poderia gerar uma duplicata.

Comment: É normal, apenas a sua irá linkar a outra pergunta, tudo bem acontecer. Nem sempre é possivel encontrar a resposta pronta devido aos titulos as vezes serem pouco trabalhados :)

Comment: @ProctonTesla, já tentou fazer apenas com CSS [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TobyMosque/7woaz74k/1/)